# Elasicsearch sort by inner field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents that one of their field looks like the following -

```
"ingredients": [{
    "unit": "MG",
    "value": 123,
    "key": "abc"
}]
```

And I would like to sort the different records according to the ascending value of specific ingredient. That is if I have 2 records which have use ingredient with key "abc", one with value 1 and one with value 2. The one with ingredient value 1 should appear first.
Each of those records may have more than on ingredient.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The search query to sort will be:

```
    {
     "sort":{
        "ingredients.value":{
    "order":"asc"}
}}
```

Comment: That's not correct because it there are other ingredients other than "abc" that will order it according to the as well. I want to sort it according to the value where the key is "abc"

Comment: To get the results to sort where the key is 'abc', you can use a filter along with the sort query.

Comment: I'm not sure that this will help because I would still like to want to see the other ingredients. Can you share an example?